# I'm not sure what Option explicit means?

Tags: scripting, vbscript, option-explicit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [what’s an option strict and explicit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2454552/whats-an-option-strict-and-explicit)

Is it about case sensitivity? Complete noob here.

Comment: Option Explicit is the single one line of code I taught my students that if they forgot that on their final exam, they would fail, regardless of the quality of the rest of the code. But yeah, duplicate.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen This question was about VBScript, the duplicate is to do with VB.Net which leads to confusion as the syntax for declaring variables is different.

Comment: That might be true, but it's still the same core answer, it forces you to declare all variables.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen still confusing for those looking for VBScript specific answers, you only have to look at [answer given here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2860637/692942) adding to confusion with VB.Net examples. Also VBScript has no concept of `Option Strict` just `Option Explicit`.

Answer (score 3):

According to [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/scripting-articles/bw9t3484(v=vs.84)):

> Used at file level to force explicit declaration of all variables in that file.

Otherwise, you can just use a variable without having to declare it first.

They even included an example:

```
Option Explicit On   ' Force explicit variable declaration.
Dim MyVar   ' Declare variable.
MyInt = 10   ' Undeclared variable generates error.
MyVar = 10   ' Declared variable does not generate error.
```

Comment: it lets you "declare" variables just by using it for the first time. In the sample above, MyInt becomes a variable just by using it without a Dim statement. ALWAYS use Option Explicit if you can, it will save you many headaches. Dim is an explicit variable declaration, MyInt above is an implicit one.

Answer (score 0):

When option explicit is off visual basic allows you to implicitly declare a variable by assigning a value to it. This is a really bad idea as misspelling a variable name would silently create a new variable causing a very hard to find bug.

```
Option Explicit Off
Imports System
Public Class ImplicitVariable
 Public Shared Sub Main()
  a = 33
  Console.WriteLine("a has value '{0}' and type {1}", a, a.GetType())
 End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: VBScript does not support the `Imports` statement.